# Count() Specifying Uncounted Value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL Server, if you use COUNT(column name) it returns the number of rows in that column which have a non-null value (i.e., it counts the rows, ignoring nulls).

Is there any way to do something similar, but allowing you to tell it which values to ignore? For example, if I wanted to count all the rows in a table which have a value which is NOT 1, I could do something like COUNTNOT(column name,1). That would count all the rows in the specified column which have a value NOT 1.

Answer (score 4):

You may use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN some_val <> 1 THEN 1 END) AS cnt
FROM yourTable;
```

The above logic is that `COUNT` will count one whenever some value is not equal to 1.  Otherwise, it falls on the `ELSE` conditional, which if not present defaults to the value `NULL`.  Since `NULL` is not counted, any value other than 1 would contribute zero to the count.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put what you want to exclude in a `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT COUNT(some_val) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE some_val <> 1
```

Comment: . . . This also correct, but will eliminate the result-set, which might not OP wants.

Comment: I am just answering the question as stated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful about `NULL` values.  I would recommend:

```
select sum(case when column in (<values to ignore>) then 0 else 1 end)
```

This will count `NULL` values as not in the list (even if `NULL` is in the list).  To ignore `NULL` values (as well), switch the logic to:

```
select sum(case when column not in (<values to ignore>) then 1 else 0 end)
```

*and be sure `NULL` is not in the list*.